# Logical Issue in MongoDB Search Filter | NodeJS

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate, logic-error

I am working on a cab booking api. The issue i am facing on is a getAllBookings api which will be used by admin to get the history of all the bookings from booking database. Speaking of database, i shall share the database model for my booking model and user model in a bit. The issue i am facing is, when i make a search query using the userId or driverId in params i get the response properly along with all the details with that particular id. However, when i try to send name query or email query in params for the same user of that userId, it returns an empty bookings array.
Following is my Booking model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },

    driver: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },

    pickupLocation: {
        address: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        latitude: {
            type: Number 
        },

        longitude: {
            type: Number  
        },
    },

    dropoffLocation: {
        address: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },

        latitude: {
            type: Number,    
        },

        longitude: {
            type: Number,    
        },
    },


    fare: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },

    bookingStatus: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'Available',
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Booking", bookingSchema);
```

User model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please add your Name"],
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please add the user email address"],
        unique: [true,"Email address already taken"],
        trim: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please add the password"],
        trim: true,
    },

    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please add Phone Number"],
        trim: true
    },

    role: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'user',
        enum: ['admin', 'user', 'driver'],
    },

    licenseNumber: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },

    carModel: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },

    carNumber: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },

    isDeleted: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },

    isAvailable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },

    location: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point']
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number] //lat and long
        }
    },

},
{
    timestamps: true
});

// Index the location field for geospatial queries
userSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

And here is the controller function for your referrence:

```
const getAllBookings = async(req, res) => {
    logger.info('Inside getAllBookings');
    try{
        const { 
            page = 1, 
            limit = 10,
            name, 
            email, 
            role, 
            userId, 
            driverId,
        } = req.query;

        let filter = {};

        if (name) {
            filter['user.name'] = { $regex: name, $options: 'i' };
        }

        if (email) {
            filter['user.email'] = { $regex: email, $options: 'i' };
        }

        if(role){
            filter['user.role'] = role;
        }

        if(userId){
            filter.user = userId;
        }

        if(driverId){
            filter.driver = driverId;
        }

        const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

        console.log(filter);


        const bookings = await Booking.find(filter)
            .populate('user driver')
            .skip(skip)
            .limit(limit)
            .sort({createdAt: -1})
            .lean()
            .exec();

            console.log("bookings", bookings);

            const count = await Booking.countDocuments(filter);
            const totalPages = Math.ceil(count / limit);

        res.status(200).json({bookings, totalPages, currentPage: +page});
    } catch(error){

        logger.error(`Error in getAllBookings: ${error.message}`);
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Server Error',
        });
    }
};
```

This is the postman response when [an id is sent in query params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw5Le.png) |
This is the postman response when [the name of the user with the above id is sent in query params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylqxH.png) |
As you can see it only gives results when the id is passed. Please assist me to debug this because i want it to be functional when name or email is sent as well.

I tried to debug it by consoling some lines. But still i was not able to figure out the issue